# Sub menu item not found by system

Tags: theming, 8

I'm try to overwrite the menu.html.twig file to support my menu structure.

My menu has some links and sublinks (only one level deep). Now when I write the menu.html.twig file I only to all the root links. No subitems can be found.

Can someone tells me what I'm doing wrong?

My source code of menu.html.twig looks like:

```
{% import _self as menus %}

<ul class="nav side-menu">

{% for item in items %}

{% if item.below | length == 0 %}
  <li {% if item.in_active_trail%}class="current-page"{% endif %}>
    {{link(item.title, item.url)}}
    </li>
{% else %}
  <li><a><i class="fa fa-edit"></i> item.title <span class="fa fa-chevron-down"></span></a>
    <ul class="nav child_menu">

      {% for subItem in item.below %}
      <li>{{link(subItem.title, subitem.url)}}}</li>
      {% endfor %}
    </ul>

{% endif %}

{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

My menu structure in Drupal looks like: 
[image]

Comment: I am not following. It isn't entirely clear what you are attempting to accomplish. What are you specifically doing to the menu that requires you theme it differently?

Comment: I want a menu like https://camo.githubusercontent.com/0fc2018c171a0d6e721ad421391c006f316eee03/68747470733a2f2f63646e2e636f6c6f726c69622e636f6d2f77702f77702d636f6e74656e742f75706c6f6164732f73697465732f322f67656e74656c656c6c612d61646d696e2d74656d706c6174652d707265766965772e6a7067.

Comment: You want to have a menu that has headers that have a collapsing accordion type of element?

Comment: Yes indeed I want a collasable accordion menu of elements

Comment: I almost have it. Only I can't find the url of the below item. When I loop over all the below items and use the <li>{{link(subItem.title, subitem.url)}}}</li> syntax I got an error.

Comment: I am looking around for a simpler solution for this. I don't think you need to delve as deep as you are. I am thinking an easier solution would be a combination of ctools.module and superfish.module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a way to display the menu correctly.

```
{% import _self as menus %}

<ul class="nav side-menu">

{% for item in items %}

{% if not item.below %}
  <li {% if item.in_active_trail%}class="current-page"{% endif %}>
    {{link(item.title, item.url)}}
    </li>
{% else %}
  <li><a><i class="fa fa-edit"></i> {{item.title}} <span class="fa fa-chevron-down"></span></a>
    <ul class="nav child_menu">

      {% for subItem in item.below %}
        <li><a href="{{ path(subItem.url.routename, {(subItem.url.routeParameters|keys|first) : (subItem.url.routeParameters|first)}) }}">{{subItem.title}}</a></li>
      {% endfor %}
    </ul>

{% endif %}

{% endfor %}
</ul>
```